# How to refer to a global type from within a class that has a nested type with the same name?

Tags: swift, scope, swift2, nested-class, scoping

I have a class declared at the global scope and another class with the same name that is nested within some class.

```
class Address {
    var someProperty: String?
}

class ThirdPartyAPI {
    class Address {
        var someOtherProperty: String?
        init(fromAddress address: Address) {
            self.someOtherProperty = address.someProperty
        }
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I refer to a global class instead of the inner one from its initialiser? In the example given I've got an error `Value of type 'ThirdPartyAPI.Address' has no member 'someProperty'`, which means that compiler refers to the inner `Address` instead of a global one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `typealias`

```
class Address {
    var someProperty: String?
}

typealias GlobalAddress = Address

class ThirdPartyAPI {
    class Address {
        var someOtherProperty: String?
        init(fromAddress address: GlobalAddress) {
            self.someOtherProperty = address.someProperty
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to types uniquely by prepending the module name.
So if

```
class Address {
    var someProperty: String?
}
```

is defined in "MySuperApp" then you can refer to it as
`MySuperApp.Address`:

```
class ThirdPartyAPI {

    class Address {
        var someOtherProperty: String?
        init(fromAddress address: MySuperApp.Address) {
            self.someOtherProperty = address.someProperty
        }
    }
}
```

(But if you have a choice then try to avoid the ambiguity to make
your code easier to understand.)